# How to affect line spacing in only one group on the title page?

Tags: formatting, line-spacing

I am trying to set up a title page for my summaries of the classes I take. The problem lies with the line spacing for the title being too small and me not being able to change just that.

My .sty-file contains the following code (the group I want to change is set between %---):

```
\ProvidesPackage{setupJojo}[2015/04/11 v0.1 Setup]

% Language, character and typeset setup
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[german]{babel}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}

% Maths setup
\RequirePackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

% Formating
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Custom commands
\newcommand*{\newWord}[1]{\textit{#1}}

% Title page
\newcommand*{\titleJojo}{
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begingroup
    \center
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

    {\LARGE A summary of}\\[\baselineskip]

    % ------------------------------------------------
    {\Huge\bfseries \nameJojo}\\[\baselineskip] % the name of the class
    % ------------------------------------------------

    {held by}\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    {\large \textsc{\dozentJojo}} % name of the lecturer

    \vfill
    {\textsc{J0hj0h}}\par

    \endgroup}
```

I use the title page code e.g. in this file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{setupJojo}

\newcommand*{\nameJojo}{The name of the class}
\newcommand*{\dozentJojo}{The professor's name}

\begin{document}
    \titleJojo
    \tableofcontents

% all my stuff...

\end{document}
```

I already tried the `setspace`-package, as you can see in the imports of the .sty-file.
`\begin{onehalfspace}...\end{onehalfspace}` affected the *following* paragraph, too.
`\setstretch{2.0}` inside the group had no effect at all.

Apart from those two, I didn't manage to find any more possible solutions, sadly.

How can I simply add a bit more line spacing to that one group without messing up the following paragraph?

*EDIT:*
Changing the line from `{\Huge\bfseries \nameJojo}\\[\baselineskip]` to `{\Huge\bfseries \nameJojo \par}` solved the problem, as Harish Kumar helped to discover. Thanks! :)

Comment: You didn't change line spacing in your code at all. Which lines you want to expand?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I want to change the line that is between the `%------------`s in the .sty-file. I removed the attempts I made, since they did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `\center` is wrong. Use `\centering`. And change the title command like this:

```
% ------------------------------------------------
    {\setstretch{1.5} \Huge\bfseries \nameJojo \par\vspace{\baselineskip}} % the name of the class %% or          \onehalfspacing or \doublespacing
% ------------------------------------------------
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage{setupJojo}
%----your package here ----------------
\ProvidesPackage{setupJojo}[2015/04/11 v0.1 Setup]

% Language, character and typeset setup
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[german]{babel}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}

% Maths setup
\RequirePackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}

% Formating
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Custom commands
\newcommand*{\newWord}[1]{\textit{#1}}

% Title page
\newcommand*{\titleJojo}{
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begingroup
    \centering               %%% \center is wrong
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

    {\LARGE A summary of}\\[\baselineskip]

    % ------------------------------------------------
    {\setstretch{1.5} \Huge\bfseries \nameJojo \par} % the name of the class %% or          \onehalfspacing or \doublespacing
    % ------------------------------------------------
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    {held by}\\[0.25\baselineskip]
    {\large \textsc{\dozentJojo}} % name of the lecturer

    \vfill
    {\textsc{J0hj0h}}\par

    \endgroup}
%--------------------------------------

\newcommand*{\nameJojo}{The name of the class just more text to show the line spacing just more text to show the line spacing just more text to show the line spacing just more text to show the line spacing just more text to show the line spacing }
\newcommand*{\dozentJojo}{The professor's name}

\begin{document}
    \titleJojo
    \tableofcontents

% all my stuff...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you can get rid of `setspace` package by using `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` instead of `\setstretch{1.5}` (Thanks to egreg).

Comment: There still is a lot of space between the title and "held by". Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: With `\linespread{1.5}\selectfont` instead of `\setstretch{1.5}` one avoids `setspace`.

Comment: I changed it to `{\Huge\bfseries \nameJojo \par}` and now it has set good line spacing on its own. What is the difference of `\par` inside and `\\\` outside of the group?

Comment: @J0hj0h `\par` inside is needed to make the `\baselinestretch` to take effect.