# How to have a newline after a manual break in LaTex Article Title?

Tags: line-breaking, titles

I want to have a general approach causing a newline after a break in the `title` field without using bugs in 3rd party packages. 
I know the thread [How do I manually break a line in a custom title of Maine University package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60493/13173) which is only about one university package. 
Approaches discussed in the thread do not work here: `\protect\\`, `\parbox` and other attempts: `\vspace{}`, ...
Code and its output in Fig. 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\title{Using ionizing potatoes and effects on hippocambuctemia and
horshoes in happiem mode locations\\ 
\large RESEARCH PAPER}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Expected output: newline between the normal text and the capitalised text
Line break start: just before `\large`, or any suitable punctuation mark

Comment: \vspace? Probably?

Comment: There is also a Q/A "How to customize my titlepage" that might interest you.

Comment: what is the question here? your input has a `\\ ` and the output shows a linebreak. What else do you expect?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Newline there.

Comment: which is what you get, so what is the question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is no newline, just a break. I want space between the two parts.

Comment: ???? what do you mean by a newline if not a linebreak, if you want more space use `\\[5cm]`  This seems to just be asking how to use `\\ ` and unrelated to titles.

Comment: oh by "newline" you were meaning a vertical space as opposed to just a linebreak. I would never have guessed that.

Comment: @David a Word user would call that newline, i think.

Comment: @Johannes_B what's Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Using ionizing potatoes and effects on hippocambuctemia and
  horshoes in happiem mode locations\\
  {\large RESEARCH PAPER}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Optionally, use `\\[2ex]` (or whatever spacing you prefer).

The spacing you're seeing with your code can be explained, of course.

The title is set in `\LARGE` size, which means, for `article` at 10pt, font size 17pt (actually 17.28pt) on a 22pt baseline skip; on the other hand, `\large` has 12pt size on 14pt.

The `\\` break ends a paragraph, because the title is processed under the scope of `\centering`, which is so typeset on a 22pt baseline skip; the second part again makes a paragraph (there is an implicit `\par` at the end) typeset on a 14pt baseline skip.

With braces around `{\large RESEARCH PAPER}`, the effect of `\large` will end *before* the implicit `\par` is executed, so the baselineskip will again be 22pt.

[image]

However, a strategy such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Using ionizing potatoes and effects on hippocambuctemia and
  horshoes in happiem mode locations\\[2ex]
  \large RESEARCH PAPER\\WHATEVER}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

is necessary if you need two lines in `\large` and them not to be excessively spaced.

[image]

Take your pick.

Comment: Confirmed! All options here work.

Comment: Don't we have a suitable duplicate? This trivial question must have been asked before.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- this is related: [How to affect line spacing in only one group on the title page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238229/579) (the use of `\par` is mentioned only in a note though)